# solidifying yeast in bottles

Tags: yeast-cultures

I brew using NA Bud.Primary fermentation in bin then secondary in primed bottles that beer originated from.bottling is done after about 1 week then left for three weeks to clear.only slight problem is sediment in bottom of bottles.beer has to be put in glass or else drinking yeasty beer. Ihave heard of using Gelatin to solidify sediment but have never tried it.
Can anyone give advice on how to use it?I.E. Preparation of Gelatin,when to add it and will it affect carbonation??

Kevin

Answer (score 3):

Gelatin will help clear beer, but will not reduce or help pack down yeast sediment in bottles. To do that, you need to allow the yeast to settle longer or in colder conditions (fridge), or both. But you will not be able to drink from a bottle without yeast.

To fine with gelatin to make your beer clear, you should do it in the fermenter. Mix 1 tsp. of gelatin in 2/3 Cup water in a microwave-safe glass cup. Heat it 15-20 seconds at a time, to get it to 155°F. You will see the gelatin "bloom" and dissolve. Give the mixture one more stir and pour it into your beer in the fermenter. It works better if you do this while cold crashing. Give it about 2 days to work.